# Use React Js to create Desktop like menu in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, angularjs-directive

i found a [good menu creator for React Js](https://github.com/nmanandhar/react-app-menu) but my entire application is in AngularJs so i only want to use the menu create to create the home page menu only while the rest of the work will be done by angularjs. However i googled for solutions for this but none seems to solve my problem now for close to 3 days.

My react Js funtion for creating the menu is as follows:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import {Keys, Menu, MenuBar, Separator} from 'react-app-menu';
    
    function MenuToolBar() {
        const handleMenuSelect = (menuId) => {
            toggleLoading(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
                openModal();
                setSelectedFile({name: menuId });
            }, 500);
        };
    
        const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState({});
        const [showModal, toggleModal] = useState(false);
    
        const openModal = () => {
            toggleModal(true);
        };
    
        const closeModal = () => {
            toggleModal(false);
        };
        
        const onFolderSelect = (): void => {
            console.log('Folder selected');
        };
    
        return (<div style={{background: '#FBFBFB', borderBottom: '1px solid rgb(218, 220, 224)'}}>
            <MenuBar onSelect={handleMenuSelect}>
                <Menu label='File' focusKey={"F"}>
                    <Menu label='New'>
                        <Menu menuId='NewNotebook' label='Notebook'}/>
                        <Menu menuId="NewNote" label='Note' hotKeys={Keys.ctrlAlt('N')}/>
                        <Separator/>
                        <Menu label="Folder" hotKeys={Keys.ctrlAlt("F")}
                              onSelect={onFolderSelect}/>
                    </Menu>
                    <Menu label='Settings' hotKeys={Keys.altShift("S")}/>
                </Menu>
                <Menu label='Edit' focusKey='E'>
                    <Menu menuId='search' label='Search' hotKeys={Keys.ctrlShift('F')}/>
                    <Menu menuId='undo' label='Undo' hotKeys={Keys.ctrl('Z')}/>
                    <Menu menuId='rename' label='Rename' hotKeys={Keys.shift('F6')}/>
                </Menu>
                <Menu label='View' focusKey='V'>
                    <Menu menuId='toolbar' label='Toolbars' checked={showToolbar} hotKeys={Keys.ctrlAlt("T")}/>
                    <Menu menuId='statusBar' label='StatusBar'/>
                    <Menu menuId='toolTips' label='Tooltips' checked={showTooltip} hotKeys={Keys.ctrlAltShift("T")}/>
                </Menu>
            </MenuBar>
        </div>);
    }
```

I tired to use directives for this is angular but am stuck

Angularjs Directive is below:-

```
    angular.module( "Demo" ).directive(
        "reactMenu",
        function reactMenuDirective( ReactMenu ) {
            return({
                link: link,
                scope: {
                    menu: "=",
                    onMenuClick: "&"
                }
            });
            function link( scope, element, attributes ) {
                scope.$watch( "menu", renderReactElement );
                scope.$on( "$destroy", unmountReactElement );
                function renderReactElement() {
                    var props = {
                        menu: scope.menu,
                        onMenuClick: function( menuId ) {
                            scope.$apply(
                                function changeViewModel() {
                                    scope.onMenuClick({
                                        like: menuId
                                    });
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    };
                    React.render(
                        React.createElement( ReactMenu, props ),
                        element[ 0 ]
                    );
                }
                function unmountReactElement() {
                    React.unmountComponentAtNode( element[ 0 ] );
    
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Any help on how to achieve this in AngularJs with React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embeding a react component in `angularjs`, just for using a library, is not a good idea in general and it will take additional efforts to integrate them.

However if you really want, you can do it with creating a `<div id="react-root"></div>` in your `angularjs` app, and then render the `react` menu inside it. (for more details, search for `how to embed react in angularjs`.)

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyReactMenu />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

But you better to use `js` or `jquery` or `angularjs` or `bootstrap`. for example bootstrap supports dropdowns with submenus ([link](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns)). just search for `javascript sub menu library` to find some alternatives.

However i embedding this react menu inside angularjs and it worked:
(Run it online on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/PoNoZYe))

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<menu-directive></menu-directive>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('ctrl', ctrl);
function ctrl($scope, $filter){
    loadReact()
}

app.directive("menuDirective", function() {
    return {
        template : "<div><h1>I am angular!</h1><div id='root'></div></div>",
        controller: 'ctrl'
    };
});
</script>

<script>
  var loadReact  = ()=> {
    // first compile your react app, then put the compiled script here
  }
</script>
<!-- i compiled this reactjs script -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ya3ya6/stackplay_2_menu/script.js"></script>
```

Run it online on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/PoNoZYe)

Comment: Thanks for this.. Let me now try in my app. I will get back. But quickly how about the menu functions on click, i would like to have all this in my main controller in angularjs.

Comment: Somehere in your codepen i saw your comment **put reactjs compiled script here** . I was wondering if i will put in the raw codes for the menu structure

Comment: @IppezRobert you mean you don't understand what you should put on there? you should create a react application with `create-react-app`, import the react library for menu, build it, so it will give you a bundle `.js` file. you should put the content of that file on "put reactjs compiled script here" section. i did it (compiled the react menu app and i did put the content) on the next line. like this: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ya3ya6/stackplay_2_menu/script.js

Comment: @IppezRobert you may wonder why you should remove mine and put your code ? that's because currently the menu doesn't call any function on `onclick` , and it doesn't have your custom items. if you want to change it, you should recompile it. and note that 1. working with `reactjs` it's not as easy as you may think, if you're not familiar with it. 2. you better to switch to `angular 2+`, cause `angularjs` is so old 3. you better to not use this (embedding the react on angular.). just use another lib.

Comment: @IppezRobert here is my repo for this (note that branch is stack-show-q2): https://github.com/ya3ya6/ReactPlay1/blob/stack-show-q2/src/stackoverflow_play/q2_menu.js you can clone the repo. then to run you should install `nodejs`. then `yarn install`, then `yarn start` for running the development server.then you should press `control + u` to see the source of the html page. then you should click on several `.js` files (`script` tags), and copy the content of them and concat (join) them to each other (in right order.). that's the thing you should put on `put reactjs compiled script here` section

Comment: @IppezRobert and again it's not the recommended way. even for someone familiar with `react`, this way is not a good way. if you're not familiar with react, you probably can't set it up correctly since you should change the callbacks and etc to customize the menu.

Comment: @IppezRobert i added the support for `onclick` : https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/PoNoZYe (you can now click on item menus). changes: in `react`, on `handleMenuSelect`, i used this code: `if (typeof angularMenuSelect !== "undefined") eval("angularMenuSelect('" + menuId + "')");` this way you can call `angularMenuSelect` function which is an angular callback (i also changed it to `var loadReact  = (angularMenuSelect)=> {` and also `loadReact((menuId) => {alert("clicked on " + menuId)});`).

Comment: I got it to work... Thanks alot for your generous help. I will try using angular 2+

Comment: @IppezRobert No problem. happy codding.